# LCD : what is the material inside

Tags: lcd

does anyone know what is exact name(s) of liquid crystal material used in modern LCD's and how big should be electric field to make it change polarization?

**Update for the second bounty:** My idea is that I want to make LCD at home. I can get everything except these twisted nematic crystals, and I haven't found any papers or information on how they should be used (like required electric field, preventing electrolysis, required thinkness), or under which names I can buy them.

Comment: lots of materials, but it's built on glass of semiconductor material.

Comment: It's not really a crystal structure but borrows its name from the anisotropic properties (different depending on the angle you look at it), which are typical for crystals. Glass for instance is amorphous, which implies isotropy, and indeed the optical properties of glass are the same for all directions.

Comment: Regarding anisotropy in crystals: http://www.evilmadscientist.com/article.php/pennmuseum

Comment: Here's a good link originally submitted by [parulpatel](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/4233/parulpatel) with background and assembly information, and quite a few sources in books and periodicals: http://www.madehow.com/Volume-1/Liquid-Crystal-Display-LCD.html

Comment: Will try and hunt down my 3rd year project notes. I built some bistable lcd's from scratch - pretty straightforward. If I find them I'll POP info up here, but this was 19 years ago...

Comment: @BarsMonster - You have a high-vacuum system at home? Cool. Also, you will almost certainly need a vacuum-deposition rig. Big $\$\$\$\$$

Comment: @Fake Name : You will be surprised, but this is exactly what I am working on ;-) Most of equipment is already here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site (in German) has info, and kits, for building your own LCDs:
http://fluessigkristalle.com/

Answer (score 4):

The crystal substance is known as "[Twisted Nematic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_nematic_field_effect)" crystal.  These operate by twisting between 0° and 90° thus polarizing the light as it passes through.  A second polarizing filter either allows or blocks the polarized light, thus making the black areas you see on the LCD.

A Twisted Nematic crystal typically requires a potential of around 1V to twist fully through 90°.

Comment: Yes, I am particularly interested in names of specific "Twisted Nematic" crystals used. LCD structure itself is pretty clear.

Comment: I've always wondered, where can you buy Liquid Twisted Nematic crystals?

Comment: @kurtnelle - yeah, this is also what I am interested in :-D

Answer (score 1):

Some Web search fun turns up:

4'-Propoxy-[1,1'-Biphenyl]-4-carbonitrile (C16H15NO), which is a powder

Trans-1-(bromomethyl)-4-propylcyclohexane (C10H19Br), which is a liquid

Comment: Here's an answer that the answerer doesn't understand himself and that doesn't help the asker... ;-)

Comment: @Federico Well, this allows me to find a supplier to buy 25kg of this thing :-)

Comment: @Linker3000 Could you suggest any references which tells that this is the one used in LCD's and any details about it? Also, not sure how powder might be used in LCD.

Comment: @Federico Russo - with chemical names like that, it helps *me* understand I don't ever want to crack one open and find out what effects it might have on things =P

Answer (score 0):

Another common chemical to use in LCD screens is [MBBA](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?InChI=InChI%3D1/C18H21NO/c1-3-4-5-15-6-10-17%2811-7-15%2919-14-16-8-12-18%2820-2%2913-9-16/h6-14H%2C3-5H2%2C1-2H3/b19-14%2B%0A), or N-(4-Methoxybenzylidene)-p-n-butylaniline.

If you do experiment with this substance, please heed these warnings.  From [this MSDS](http://www.chemcas.com/material/cas/archive/26227-73-6.asp), you can see that while the material *is* poisonus if you ingest/inhale it (or get it in an open wound or your eyes), it just causes some skin irritation if you get it on you.  If you do happen to get the material *inside* of your body, then you should seek medical assistance (as it will begin to make methemoglobin in your blood).  However, if you get just a bit on your finger (externally only), wash your hands with soap and water and you should be fine.